# Evolution of the curvature perturbation on super-horizon scales

Tags: cosmology, curvature, gauge-invariance, cosmological-inflation

energy conservation equation(1st order) in density perturbations and on superhorizon scales( $k<<aH $) implies

$\delta \dot{\rho } = -3H(\delta p +  \delta \rho) + 3 \dot{\Psi} ( \rho + p) $
we have

$\delta p = \delta p_{\alpha} + c^2_{s} \delta \rho$
and $c^2_{s} = \dfrac{\delta p_{\beta}}{\delta \rho}$
where we define $ \delta p_{\alpha }$ to be the non-adiabatic component of pressure perturbation and $\delta p_{\beta}$ to be the adiabatic component.

It is to be shown that if perturbations are adiabatic, then the curvature is constant *outside* the horizon on a *uniform-density gauge*. Furthermore, I would like to show that this is the case for all gauges.
I am unsure where to start. My intuition is start out with the fact that

$R  = \Psi + \dfrac{\delta \phi}{\dot \phi } H $ and that given some $\delta t $ causes the same perturbation for all quantities perturbed adiabatically in the universe $\delta t= \dfrac{\delta X}{\dot X}$

However, I am unclear as to how to move forward.

Comment: You should work with gauge-invariant quantities then.  See Bardeen's seminal paper on this topic: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.22.1882

Comment: The curvature is in fact gauge invariant. I am still having trouble getting to show that $\dot R = 0$